# Reverse logging order in PHP monolog/monolog

Tags: php, monolog

I'm using monolog library for logging to text file..
It logs ordered by date:

```
[2016-10-19 03:39:05] name.WARNING: Foo [] [] 
[2016-10-19 03:40:05] name.ERROR: Bar [] [] 
[2016-10-19 03:41:32] name.WARNING: Foo [] [] 
[2016-10-19 03:42:18] name.ERROR: Bar [] [] 
[2016-10-19 03:43:42] name.WARNING: Foo [] []
```

I want to reverse this order so that most recent will be most top..

Is there an easy way to do this with monolog (perhaps some hidden setting?)

Answer (score 0):

This code will read your log file and display the last lines $qtd_rows in reverse

```
$file = 'error.log';
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$linecounter = $qtd_rows;
$pos = -2;
$beginning = false;
$this->lines = array();

while ($linecounter > 0) {
    $t = " ";
    while ($t != "\n") {
      if(fseek($handle, $pos, SEEK_END) == -1) {
           $beginning = true; break; 
      }`enter code here`
      $t = fgetc($handle);
      $pos --;
    }

    if($beginning) rewind($handle);

    $line = fgets($handle);

    $lines[$lines-(--$linecounter)-1] = $line;

    if($beginning) break;
}

fclose ($handle);

foreach($lines as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
};
```